# Why does render_to_response work even if it does not match the url in urls.py?

Tags: python, django

I have a django project where a view calls render_to_response using a different number of parameters to that specified in urls.py. When I try to do something similar elsewhere I get an error saying that the view is expecting a specific number of parameters. How can this be so?

from urls.py

```
url(r'^report_view/(?P<report_type>.*)/(?P<date_from>.*)/(?P<date_to>.*)/$', report_view),
url(r'^scanner_times/(?P<scanner_id>\d+)/$', scanner_times),
```

from my template

from views.py

```
def scanner_times(request, scanner_id):
    current_scanner = get_object_or_404(Scanner, pk=scanner_id)
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(scanner=scanner_id).order_by('date_requested')
    # loop over each ticket, adding a new entry to the list if it's the first ticket for that day, or incrementing if the day is already in it.
    userid = request.user.username
    date_count = {}
    for ticket in tickets:
        if ticket.approved:
            datestr = str(ticket.date_scheduled)
            datestr = datestr[:10]
            if datestr in date_count:
                date_count[datestr] += 1
            else:
                date_count[datestr] = 1
    sorted_date_count = sorted(date_count.items(), key = itemgetter(0))

    return render_to_response('scanner_times.html',
                            {'tickets': tickets,
                            'current_scanner':current_scanner,
                            'date_count':date_count,
                            'sorted_date_count':sorted_date_count},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

how can that work? I'm confused!

Comment: I'm confused about why your confused. Why would render_to_response care how many parameters are in the URL?

Comment: When asking for questions like "why doesn't this code work" you should include the traceback you get.

Comment: Using `.*` in the template could be causing problems, because it will match all characters including forward slashes. You would be better off with something like `url(r'^report_view/(?P<report_type>[\w-]+)/(?P<date_from>[\w-]+)/(?P<date_to>[\w-]+/$'`.

Comment: "It’s not recommended and is likely to be deprecated in the future." - From the [docs for `render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)

Comment: This code actually works Ilja - hence no traceback. I will post the code that doesn't work - if I cannot figure out the problem from the helpful answers that have been given.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion there. [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) is being used once the URL has been matched and you are inside the view which is serving the URL.

This is the definition of `render_to_response`:

```
render_to_response(template_name, context=None, context_instance=_context_instance_undefined, 
                   content_type=None, status=None, dirs=_dirs_undefined, using=None)
```

In your case:

```
return render_to_response('scanner_times.html',
                    {'tickets': tickets,
                    'current_scanner':current_scanner,
                    'date_count':date_count,
                    'sorted_date_count':sorted_date_count},
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

here, your template is `'scanner_times.html'` and then you have the context dict and then you have the `context_instance`.

This function will pass this context into the template, render the `'scanner_times.html'` and return it.

It has nothing to do with the `urls` at this moment.